# Some walls messed up when I solidified the walls

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, modifiers

I made a house [image] but right here in the corner and other places to, It messes up when solidify it. Does anyone know why? [image]

Comment: plz attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to inspect

Comment: You have a non manifold mesh. There is an edge with three faces

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first screenshot, I see that the wall on the left is black, and not grey like the adjacent one. Can you check the normals? If you select the face and use the spacebar and type 'flip normals', it should turn the face in the correct direction.

Barry